# $and not working with $lte and $gte

Tags: mongodb

I have below query for Mongo DB and seems it is not working for me :

```
db.getCollection('dummy_price').find({
     "$and": [ 
        { "price" : { "$gte" : 249.3490175}} , { "price" : { "$lte" : 275.5962825}}]  
        })
```

I am trying to get the records where price is within this range, there is record present for this criteria but I am not getting the result.

Can somebody suggest what is wrong here?

Amandeep

Comment: `.find({ "price" : { "$gte" : 249.3490175,  "$lte" : 275.5962825}})`. All conditions are **already** AND conditions..That's a correction on the shorter version query, but it's basically the same statement. If you don't get results then there is nothing in between. Possibly "strings" in the "price"? Show a document if you are not sure.

Comment: Could you [edit] your answer to show an example document which you were expecting to be returned? Maybe there's something in the data or the data structure which would help us see what's going wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this instead:

```
db.getCollection('dummy_price').find(
        { "price" : 
            { "$gte" : 249.3490175},
              "$lte" : 275.5962825}
            }
        }
)
```

Comment: by default conditions are `AND` unless you specify

Comment: @Rahul But the "long form" in the question is still valid, and actually selects the same things. Should be written this way, but it does not answer why it selects nothing. Furthermore the syntax here is incorrect.